# Sampling data at 5 MHz with 50 MHz clock in Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, oversampling

I'm trying to make a controller for the MAX31855 thermocouple IC. My FPGA works at 50 MHz and this IC works at 5 MHz, so I'm using a frequency divider to get the 5 MHz clock signal.

Now the IC is sending to the FPGA its 32 data bits, at 1 bit per clock cycle. So I don't know exactly how to sample this (5 MHz) bit stream with a 50 Mhz clock signal.

I'm also thinking in metastability problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of interface does your IC have? Usually this sounds like a non issue due to cleanly defined interfaces and existing IP /hardware transceivers.

Comment: clock enable circuit. Count to from 0 to 9, and your allow your circuit to be clocked whenever the counter = 0. You can sync the clock by resetting the counter to 5 each time you detect a transition in the incoming data. (that puts your enabled clock edge right in the centre of the incoming data stream). I can turn this into a full answer in the morning (its midnight here).

Comment: If your FPGA can output 50 MHZ or an even fraction of it you can use flip-flops to sync the 5 MHZ clock so you have no metastable jitter.

Comment: Tom Carpenter. Can you please turn that into a full answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you say "You can sync the clock by resetting the counter to 5", you mean, just the first time (for the first bit I mean), right? like in RS-232

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a frequency divider. But that is just the beginning. Indeed you have to add a synchroniser for the serial input. I looked at the datasheet and you need an SPI interface without the transmit part. That means you also need a chip select, serial/parallel converter, . I am not going to write that for you (After all that is what I earn my money with) so I am going to give you the most important snippets:

```
  always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n)
   begin
      if (!reset_n)
      begin
         ser_in_meta <= 1'b0;
         ser_in_sync <= 1'b0;     
      end
      else
      begin
         // Sync input on system clock 
         ser_in_meta <= ser_in;
         ser_in_sync <= ser_in_meta;
      end
   end

         // Divide by 10 counter
         if (clock_div==4'd9)
            clock_div <= 4'd0;
         else
            clock_div <= clock_div + 4'd1;

        // Symmetrical 1/10 system clock
        if (clock_div==4'd0)
           ser_clk <= 1'b0;
        else
           if (clock_div==4'd4)
              ser_clk <= 1'b1;

        if (sample)
        begin
           bit_count <= bit_count + 5'h1;
           // Receive: MS bit arrives first 
           shift_in  <= {shift_in[30:0],ser_in_sync};                    
        end        

   // pick up the data just before the falling clock edge 
   assign sample  = (clock_div==4'd9);
```

The Maxim datasheet says the data is changing max 40ns after the falling clock edge. So pick it up just before.

Comment: Thank you sir. What's the meaning/purpose of ser_in_meta, ser_in_sync  and ser_clk?

Comment: ser_in_meta and ..sync are what gets the asynchronous ser_in signal in phase with your system clock. I takes care of what you call *"the metastability problem"*. The MAX31855 needs a clock which we generate here named *"ser_clk"*.